# How do I remove Maven from a Eclipse java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Due to being tasked with moving our java builds from a manual build process to Teamcity, I've been checking out IntelliJ, Maven and Ant for builds.  Of the 3 due to various reasons, I've decided to go with Ant, however after converting one of the projects to a Maven project, I now cannot 'undo' this action.  Finding help anywhere has been pointless as it appears it's popular enough any time someone asks a similar question they get redirected on how to 'continue' using Maven instead.

Comment: With Tact and Diplomacy, Maven can be picky at times.. or just do what Chris said.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Right Click Project -> Maven -> Disable Maven Nature

Comment: And if there is no Maven dropdown item, what then?

Comment: Answered my own question there - re-convert to Maven then disable as you suggested.  Thank you.

Comment: Then maven is not enabled for that project. I just tested it on one of my projects. If you disable maven the maven nature then the Maven menu will no longer be available for the project.

Comment: Does the project icon folder have the small M above it to signify that it is a maven project? Also are you using kepler, juno, or another version of eclipse?

Comment: I got it.  I had to re-convert to Maven and then disable as you suggested above.  My base problem was any time I attempted to build or run I got a could not find POM file error (paraphrased) and couldn't get it to go away.  

Maybe I will take another look at Maven in the future but for now it's overkill for what we're trying to do as well as being, in my opinion, pretty invasive for what we needed.

Comment: How can you stop Maven from hijacking the JUnit run configuration classpath even after disabling the Maven project nature?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954222/how-to-force-eclipse-junit-run-configuration-to-use-project-default-classpath

Comment: You might need to delete the junit test configuration and then run it again. Right click unit test you want to run-> run as -> run configurations. Then delete the generated run configuration for that unit test. It will be recreated the next time you run it. That would be my guess

Comment: Is there a way to re-enable Maven after clicking 'Disable Maven Nature' ? Seems menu-item gets removed and there is no way back.

Comment: @Oysio I have not been using eclipse for quite some time now. You might need to open a new question for this one.