# "Could not find or load main class" after removing Maven nature and files (pom.xml, target/) from an Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I accidentally converted my project to Maven by going to *Configure > Convert to Maven Project*. Now I want to undo this. I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282700/how-do-i-remove-maven-from-a-eclipse-java-project) that I need to right click *Maven > Disable Maven Nature* and that worked fine. However I want to totally remove Maven, so I deleted the `pom.xml` and the `target` folder. When I try to run my code now, I get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

So what am I missing? How do I revert from a Maven project to a non-Maven project?

Comment: What do you mean by "run your code"? You open the main class and hit F11?

Comment: That's right, I try to execute it any way I can

Comment: Check the run configuration of the main class.

Comment: It looks fine to me, nothing out of the ordinary.. you mean Run => Run Configuration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove Maven from a Eclipse java project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282700/how-do-i-remove-maven-from-a-eclipse-java-project)

Comment: Duplicate question, with accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19282700/3347

Comment: @spoulson This question is not a duplicate. The problems appeared after the OP had applied the solution in the linked question (and performed additional steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it basically a Maven project, i.e., do you have and maintain it through a `pom.xml`? Then my suggestion is to delete the project in Eclipse but keep the files on the disk (i.e., it removes it from the workspace). Then, run a simple `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` which creates a simple Java project without the Maven nature based on the POM (so the libraries are linked and the source/output directories are set up correctly - this may solve your `ClassNotFoundError`).

If it's a simple Java project, I would advise deleting it from the workspace, removing the `.classpath` and `.project` files and importing it again with the *Create a Java project with existing sources* wizard.

Either way, make a backup of your project before you start doing anything :-)

Comment: Thanks, the second method worked great :) I just removed the pom.xml and target folder, deleted the .classpath and .project as you advised and followed steps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9280568/1482644) to import the project. Thanks!

Comment: If it was a Maven project, why would CC Inc want to delete the pom.xml? IMHO it is pretty clear from the question that the pom.xml was only created by accident.

Comment: Basically there are 2 ways of working with Maven projects, Eclipse's Maven plugin or Maven's Eclipse plugin (hehe, nice namings, right?). With the the second option, you're working with a plain Java project that has no Maven nature. Each time you touch the POM you regenerate the Eclipse project descriptors. That's why I suggested the first alternative. Probably it was clear for you, but not for me -- that's why I asked :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a Java project to a Maven project in Eclipse, the Maven Integration for Eclipse (m2eclipse) configures the Java incremental compiler to put the compiled class files in the same location as Maven would put them, i.e. `target/classes`.

So when you remove the Maven nature and delete the `target` folder, you now also have deleted the compiled class files and your project can no longer run. AFAIK, the incremental compiler doesn't detect when you remove its output files, so you need to trigger a rebuild by cleaning the project (*Project > Clean...*)

This will fix the problem that you can not launch your project, but may re-create a `target` folder. If you also want this to be "fixed", you can switch back to some other folder name for the binaries, e.g. `bin`, in the project's *Java Build Path* configuration on the *Source* tab.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense, thank you for clearing up that point for me :)

Comment: @oberlies As you suggested, I tried cleaning the project under Project –> Clean... –> Clean. Unfortunately, when I try to run the project, I still get the error message, "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer. java.lang.module.FindException: Module reasoner not found." (reasoner is the name of the only module in my project.) How do I resolve this error message?