# Can't I exclude Maven in my Spring MVC Project?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm using STS, (+ sql server driver(mssql), mybatis-spring, mybatis))
my package structure is:

```
src/main/java >>> com.sunny.myevent.controller *.domain *.persistence *.service
src/main/resources >>> com.sunny.myevent.persistence (Mapper xml files)
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

AND

```
src/main/webapp/resources/...
src/main/WEB-INF/classes
src/main/WEB-INF/spring >>> ./root-context.xml, appServlet/servlet-context.xml
src/main/WEB-INF/views >>> ./web.xml
```

What can I do to remove pom.xml and convert to spring3 mvc project without maven?

Comment: Why do you want to remove maven?

Comment: @jny It's requirement of my client.

Comment: Does he want to use something else instead? e.g. Ant, Grails?

Comment: @jny No, he manages his lib manually. I made an event page of his homepage, but he asked to exclude Maven.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282700/how-do-i-remove-maven-from-a-eclipse-java-project.  You'll need to delete pom and manage sources/libraries manually...

Comment: How are you planning to build now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build with maven, it will dump all the required jars someplace in your build or target directory. If you are creating a web application, then you'll find them all in

```
WEB-INF/lib
```

All you need to do is to take the contents of that directory (all the jar files maven puts in their) and paste them into the source folder for your web project:

src/main/WEB-INF/lib

Whatever tool you are using to build and package your app (eclipse, ant, etc), you'll need to make sure that directory is on your class path.

Delete the pom.xml file and you should be good to go.