# "java could not find the main class" and "could not read maven project"

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I'm working on java 1.6 on eclipse. Yesterday, i tried to compile it to a runnable jar, but it didn't work.
So , finnaly i tried to change the java version and i still can't compile the project. Then i tried to convert my project to Maven.
Finally, i use this solution : 
[How do I remove Maven from a Eclipse java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282700/how-do-i-remove-maven-from-a-eclipse-java-project)
But now, when i launch the project i have the error : 'Launching app' has encountered a problem. could not read maven project

in details i can read '...[FATAL] Non-readable-pom...' But i disable maven project.

And when i click ok, i can run my app, but i have a new pb what is 'the main class is not found'. I read on the net it's probably due to the java version changing.

Now, i'm looking to make the project as yesterday before those actions. I use git, so i tried to come back to the last commit but it doesn't work.

Could you give me some way or solutions?

ty, Olivier

Comment: Is your project a jar archive ?

Comment: this project is not the jar.

Comment: i fix this problem by creating a new workspace and import the project. But I lost commits

Answer (score 4):

This helped to me:

Exit Eclipse.

Delete the .metadata folder in your workspace.

Start Eclipse.

After that you can import all your projects import -> General -> existing project into eclipse. From root directory you can choose all your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem: I removed the maven aspect and the pom. The project ran fine until I restarted Eclipse the next day and got the "Non-readable-pom"

What fixed it for me was (1) edit the .classpath and remove all "pom-derived" annotations there (2) remove the m2e stuff from the .settings directory.

Answer (score 0):

Had sameproblem: I figured the .. section in pom.xml was empty. Added 'groupId' and 'artifactId' there.Then in Eclipse:
Right click Project -> Maven -> 'Update Project'
It worked.